# Making grooves in objects

Tags: modeling, mesh, topology

I'm trying to cut grooves into this handle shown in the image below. I need them cut along the red line.

[image]

I want them to be look like the grooves marked by red in this image below:

[image]

How would I got about cutting even grooves into the the mesh along the red line in the first image? I'll provide the mesh in a file.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried knife tool yet?

Comment: Here is what you want: http://imgur.com/SrdF2tT. I've used one mesh as a guide and second one as retopo. Then with several pretty basic methods like Snap to Faces and Shrinkwrap Modifier I've created Edge Flow (marked with Creases) which then allow me to indent a groove. This kind of topology will help you to always maintain base shape, control over grooves sharpness, size etc. If you want more information I can create an answer. Not step by step thou as this would be really big tutorial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would start over completely and create the topology in 2D first, in all quads, tracing the reference image.

[image: Mesh topology example]

(Sorry for the two-billion pixel screen shots. You can thank retina display.)

Anyway, if you make topology like this you can get the curves you're hoping to achieve without cutting.

Consider this a starting point, and also just an example of one possible way you could do it.

Note the tightly-spaced holding loops around the curves that add sharpness. These also serve as a buffer between those curves and the 5-poles in some spots:

[image: A 5-pole buffered by a holding loop]

*Above: A 5-pole (marked in red) buffered by a holding loop (green).*

As you've probably noticed, more closely-spaced holding loops create sharper edges.

[image: Holding loop spacing determines edge sharpness]

*Above: A more widely-spaced loop (green) will create softer edges, while a more tightly-spaced loop (orange) will create sharper edges.*

Topology is a broad topic, but it's just about collecting different techniques, and adjusting how you think about shapes. It's half art form and half math. Stick with it.

Comment: So I trace the points on what I am making with vertices and make the points I will eventually bend around, basically trace it and make a flat surface, however once I get this 2D sheet how do I properly bend everything into shape

Comment: What is the name of this modeling style so I can find tutorials

Comment: @FrosticWolf You can use Shrinkwrap modifier but you will need guide/base mesh before that, or else you will need to place vertexes manually. Check my comment under your question, if you want I can make an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using the [Knife Project tool](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/knife_subdivide.html).

In your specific case:

1. Create a curve object that follows the shape of the curve you want to cut [image]
2. Select both the curve object and the object you want to cut (note that the curve object should be selected first)
3. Jump into edit mode and click `Knife Project` on the left panel under Mesh Tools[image]

Comment: Some cleaning work will be required to get rid of Ngons and/or tris in order to make the end result ready for insetting, intruding inside and adding Subsurf

Comment: Topology horror. Zero control over it later on, and Subsurf resistant method.